# Magento on mouse over of "my cart", when there are 1 or more items in the cart, the mini-cart should display

Tags: magento

I have to achieve the below in Magento. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

1. on mouse over of "my cart", when there are 1 or more items in the cart, the mini-cart should display -- moving the mouse away causes the mini cart to hide
2. when adding items to the cart the mini cart should be shown for 10 seconds and then hide
3. clicking on "my cart" will take the user to the shopping cart page.

It would be great if i get some help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I have to implement this functionality in magento minicart. There is a link on top "My Cart". On mouse over of "my cart", when there are 1 or more items in the cart, the mini-cart should display -- moving the mouse away causes the mini cart to hide

Comment: Yeah but what have you tried ? where are you programmatically stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the block responsible for the Cart Sidebar. This has pretty much everything you need to render the cart items.

The block class is located in `/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php`

You can create a new block in your header of the type "checkout/cart_sidebar", with a custom template based on the cart sidebar template. You'll also need to update your header template the call the new child block for the mini cart.

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" 
           name="mini_cart" as="mini_cart"
           template="my_theme/checkout/cart/mini.cart.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Then in `/page/html/header.phtml` make sure you call `echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_cart');`

This should get you started. To automatically trigger the popup when a product has been added, you need to store a flag in the session, then check for this when the page is reloaded and fire your JavaScript etc. I recommend using an event observer to do this e.g. `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`

Comment: Hi, I have achieved by showing drop down  on mouse over and hide on mouseout. On mouseover I showed a dropdown, if I mouseout and moveover the the dropdown again, it is jumping.            Mouseover Script:-  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         var outer = jQuery('#adv-top-cart');
      outer.hover(function() {
   var n = jQuery('#cartHeader span').html();
   if(n > 0)
    {
              adv.cart.openmini(outer);
             }
            });
   
 
 });

Comment: This is now a Javascript/jQuery issue and out of "Magento" scope.